# App keeps force closing each time I try to run. Help needed.

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I try to run this code it force closes. And I apologize in advance because I am a noob at java.

```
package com.MrNom;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class NomActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

}
```

This was red in LogCat right before it force closed.

```
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.MrNom/com.MrNom.Mr.NomActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.MrNom.Mr.NomActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.MrNom-1.apk]
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.MrNom.Mr.NomActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.MrNom-1.apk]
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-29 18:59:40.626: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, find where you declare that activity and change it's name property from "com.MrNom.Mr.NomActivity" to "com.MrNom.NomActivity".

As you can see from your activity class, it's in package "com.MrNom", not "com.MrNom.Mr"

Answer (score 0):

to me it seems that you somehow messed up the namespaces - in the exception it says that it tries to create `com.MrNom.Mr.NomActivity` which is not found... the correct class would be (just a guess) `com.MrNom.NomActivity` - somewhere you make the runtime beleive there must be `Mr.` in there - you don't show enough code to solve this...

Comment: not sure... perhaps you can just search the project for "Mr." and see what turns up ?

Comment: um is there like an actual search or just look around for it myself?